Wi-Fi отображается как «не защищенный», но подключиться не получается
В общем, при неприятных обстоятельствах поспорил с учителем что смогу подключиться к школьному Wi-Fi, но есть загвоздка:
Wi-Fi отображается как «не защищенный», но подключиться не получается (защиты по mac адресам скорее всего нету)
Я узнал что пароль все же присутствует, но как его узнать я без понятия. У меня есть доступ к пк на которых wi-fi подключен. Через netsh … показывает что пароля нету.

Скорее всего, там как раз привязка по Mac... Так что спор проигран

Нужно было узнать mac какого-нибудь непостоянного клиента(например того же самого из кабинета информатики) и когда он отключится, подменить им свой.
Ещё проблема могла быть в отключенном dhcp, нужно узнать шлюз и подключиться по статическому ip с рандомной цыфиркой в конце
P.s: я знаю что поздно

Никогда не поздно, спасибо). Теперь буду знать
